# How to get proper title from RSS feed?

Tags: php, rss

I have a feed: https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=172360026392

With a title for example:

> No nie do wiary! Maraton Warszawski & #x2013; ki

The space between & and # is intentional, in rss there is no space. How to convert the string to pure UTF-8 so that & #x2013; will become "-"  character?

Comment: I would suggest fetching the Atom feed instead (https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom10&id=172360026392), for clearer escaping behaviour, but unfortunately it incorrectly double-escapes titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use html_entity_decode function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php